# Application on production server giving a model error

Tags: django

> RuntimeError at / Model class models.Category doesn't declare an
>   explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',         
)
```

Why am I getting this error and what needs to be done to solve this error

Comment: Well, *is* that model in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: no it is not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere, you are importing the models.py that contains Category. You can't import a model unless its app is in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: You are right....I am using from models instead of app.models....
But when I use app.models....and app.forms...
I am getting this error: ImportError at /
No module named forms